# Problems with importing libraries into typescript .ts files and cors errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, same-origin-policy

I am trying to build a fairly simple html canvas game in typescript, and for that I plan to use the Konva library. I can easily import it into my html file with `<script src="...` which should allow my program to run.
But since the typescript is in a separate folder I need to import it separately in order to not cause errors and to use suggestions in vscode. Using `import` requires that when connected to an html file it has `type="module"`, and even though all of these files are in a folder together on my desktop, importing a js file that is a module causes CORS errors.

Is there any other way to do any of this? Every answer I seem to find requires creating a local http webserver, and that really seems like way to much effort for a coding an html canvas game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install konva

in vs code is one way

Comment: actually that turns out to not work, because running that command just adds an import statement to the top of the code, which then fail because ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module```

Comment: my last suggestion would be to put the konva package in your project ... the link is https://unpkg.com/konva@8.3.3/konva.js and try to link to it that way

Comment: I have a public fetch API. But some people were telling to enable CORS as it blocks their requests. I know there is an npm package called cors. 
But I saw that many Public APIs do not have CORS enabled. I also read some articles about the security risks in CORS.

**I was asking that will it be wrong to enable CORS**. Few people are calling the API from the client-side code that is running in the browsers.
Any suggestion is gratefully accepted.